# Form validation before post

Tags: validation, symfony

I would like to already show errors of a form before the form is submitted.
I have forms where the database data is incomplete so I would like to show what's already missing before they try to save it.

However $form->isValid() only executes when the form is also submitted (which only happens on post).

I tried the validator but that gives me a list of errors without adding them to the form and it seems a bad work around if I do that myself, however I was unable to figure out form the source how to achieve this.

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(SchoolFormType::class, $school, $formOptions);
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate a submit with :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

$wasSubmitted = $form->isSubmitted();

if(!$wasSubmitted){
    $form->submit($form->getData(),false);
}

if ($form->isValid()) {
    // ...

    // next lines are to be sure that the form will always need to be submitted manualy :
    if($wasSubmitted){
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render ...
    }
}

return $this->render ...
```

See the submit method in the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Form.php#L496).

Comment: Thank you!
I tried $form->submit(null, false); but it gave me a csrf error and I wasn't sure how to replicate it. Works like a charm!